# Group files with the same name in filelist

Tags: phpstorm

All my projects contains alot of files with the same name 'file1.php file1.less file1.css file1.min.js file1.js file1.json'

Is there a plugin or a way to group all those files with same basename under eg. file1.php, just like the filewatchers does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouping relations can only be established when running watchers, so using watchers is the right way to go. It can indeed be a batch script that does nothing - this is the 'Output paths to refresh' option that matters: it should provide a pattern for files that has to be nested. For example, let you have same-named files with .php, .css and .js extensions in some folder, and like to nest the latter 2 in .php file (doesn't make much sense, but it's just an example).

- create a .bat/sh file that does nothing (echos some string, etc.)
- create a new custom file watcher, set 'php' as file type, your .bat - as a program
- specify $FileName$ and $FileDir$ as 'Arguments' and 'Working directory' respectively
- set $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js as 'Output paths to refresh'

Now when you modify your phpfile watcher will be run and nest .js and .css in .php

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to perform such nesting/grouping manually (excluding File Watchers).. and I personally know no plugin that can do this.

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113347
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7635

Comment: Do you know if it should be possible with filewatchers to somehow nest them without touching the files?

Comment: Well ... the only thing I could think of: create some shell/batch file that does nothing (or does nothing important at all, like echo few characters) and use it as File Watcher. If you configure `Output paths to refresh` field correctly (list all files that needs to be watched for -- look at examples for existing file watchers) then it may work (I see no reason why not).

Comment: Do you have any clue about that and how it could be done? a simple .sh script is not a valid "application" - also - where can I set the pattern, do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm not a Mac/Linux user -- sorry. Possibly you have forgot to add "executable" permission for that file? For pattern -- just try creating file watchers using one of the predefined templates (e.g. for TypeScript) that generates more than one file in the end (e.g. `.ts` -> `.js` + `.js.map`) -- you will see how they are listed there (e.g. `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map`)